# Interfaces cannot contain fields

Tags: c#, interface

probably a really dumb question, but I keep getting the above error with the following code:

```
public interface IAttributeOption
{
    AttributeTypeCode Type { get; set; }
}
```

You can probably tell, I'm trying to define an interface with a single property.

I know that somebody is BOUND to tell me "an interface is a virtual class, blah blah" and I want to confirm in advance I KNOW THIS! I'm clearly trying to define a property, which as far as I am aware is fine in an interface.

So what is wrong??

Thanks :)

Comment: That compiles fine for me. BTW don't call a property `Type` if you can help it.

Comment: Check VS's error list and navigate to the source of the error by double-clicking it - is this interface really the error source?

Comment: @Rawling Why should a property not being called `Type`? I mean, I think I can guess but can you explain?

Comment: Only because of the potential confusion with the `Type` class. I don't think it would actually cause any abiguities or errors in the compiler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'm clearly trying to define a property, which as far as I am aware is fine in an interface.

There's nothing wrong with this code. The error you are getting is somewhere else. Just make sure that the `AttributeTypeCode` class is defined of course.

Comment: This got me thinking. I saved, closed VS, reopened VS and the solution, built with no errors :o

Comment: @bukko Ah yes, I asked a question like that once. I feel your pain.

Answer (score 9):

> So what is wrong?

Nothing, your interface declaration is fine. Sounds like you possibly forgot to put your accessor declarations in previously:

```
public interface IAttributeOption
{
    AttributeType Type; // no { get; set; }
}
```

If it's a linked assembly you may need to do a full rebuild as you may be pulling in a cached version.

Comment: it may have been related to this, although I don't remember not having the accessor declaration. However I'm going with Darin Dimitrov as his answer helped with the "solution" (such as it was!)